# Are keywords and statements handled differently in PHP code blocks?

Tags: php, syntax, keyword

In *Programming PHP (3rd Edition)*, it says

> "Because `include` and `require` are keywords, not real statements, you must always enclose them in curly braces in conditional and loop statements" (p.58)

And then it gives the example

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    include "repeated_element.html";
}
```

I've tried this code with and without curly braces around the `include` and it seems to make no difference to me. Have I missed something?

Comment: It's a book of year 2013, throw it away.

Comment: There's no difference.

Comment: Was there ever a difference? Is the book just out of date?

Comment: I've never heard of anything like that. The idea that "keywords" behave differently would presumably also apply to things like `echo` and `return`, which definitely isn't the case.

Comment: in 2013 (PHP 5) keywords behaved as they do today in PHP 7. The book is just wrong. It may have been a "style" that the author preferred but not one I have ever heard of with over 10 years experience.